# Run GO 1.7.x test from batch file and exclude vendor

Tags: windows, batch-file, go, testing, cmd

I'm trying to run go test -v from windows command batch file.

My GO version is 1.7.1 (and can't be replaced)

go test -v .... doesn't work since I have vendor folder.

I searched and found this:
for /f "" %G in ('go list ./... ^| find /i /v "/vendor/"') do @go test %G

But it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Simply run `go run ./...`. Starting from Go 1.9, this does not execute tests in `vendor` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the link you added.
However I am using go1.7 and all answers are talking about go 1.9

Appreciate if you can reopen

Comment: Go 1.7 is more than 2 years old and is not maintained anymore, it doesn't even receive security patches. Believe me, it's better to upgrade to Go 1.11 than to keep beating a dead horse.